# active model - double belongs_to but just one at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

this is my scenario: One model called "callgroup" and a model called "payments"

```
class Callgroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end


-------------------


class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :callgroup
end
```

Now, i need to add another model called "Extragroup", and manage payments for this model with the same "payments" model.
i tried to add relations in payments table with a relations migration end changing model in

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :callgroup
  belongs_to :extragroup
end
```

The goal is to register payments in the table but refear to "Callgroup" OR to "extragroup" but without success: after changes payments are no long working.
How can i solve?

Comment: What do you mean "are no longer working"? What errors do you receive? Where do you receive them? What does your `Extragroup` model look like? BTW, at first blush this looks like a job for `polymorphic`.

Comment: extragroup, are a group of "working calls", grouped and after payed (in one or more steps). Extragroups, are a group of other kind things (extra payments for employes). i need to manage payments from some models. after this questions, i removed in payments model the relation "belongs_to" for each of 2 dependent models and now i can save record: Of course, i can retrieve payments from callgroup or extragroup but not retrieve extragroup or callgroup starting from payment "directly". Ex. Callgroup.find(12).payments is ok but i can't do Payments.find(3).extragroup, but it's not a problem